# Insert label and comment tag into ontology with SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql

I want to add dynamically information in my ontology. I succeeded  to add  something like this

```xml
<myOntology:Diseases rdf:about="&myOntology;Cough">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="&myOntology;Diseases" />
</myOntology:Diseases>
```

with

```
INSERT DATA { 
GRAPH <http://www.semanticweb.org/alexandrina/ontologies/2013/3/myOntology>  
   {
    <http://www.semanticweb.org/alexandrina/ontologies/2013/3/myOntology#Cough>             
    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>
    <http://www.semanticweb.org/alexandrina/ontologies/2013/3/myOntology#Diseases>  
   }
}
```

But now I want to add label or comment properties. For example, to obtain

```xml
<rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">Cough</rdfs:comment>
<rdfs:comment xml:lang="ro">Tusea</rdfs:comment>
```

I've tried a lot of queries, but without success.  What should such a query be?

Comment: Just a note about the example, the RDF/XML syntax `<myOntology:Diseases rdf:about="&myOntology;Cough">…</myOntology:Diseases>` already says that `&myOntology;Cough rdf:type myOntology:Diseases`, so the inner `<rdf:type …/>` is redundant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I see you've posted a few questions, and just wanted to let you know that if they've worked for you, you can [accept the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/225437) to let other users know that the answer worked for your question (and to reward the answer-er with some reputation points).  In this case, did the provided SPARQL query work for you?  If not, can  you let us know what's not working about it, and perhaps it can be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

Your insert query can be written a bit more concisely by using prefixes, and by using the `a` shorthand for `rdf:type`:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/alexandrina/ontologies/2013/3/myOntology#>
INSERT DATA { 
GRAPH <http://www.semanticweb.org/alexandrina/ontologies/2013/3/myOntology>
   {
    :Cough a :Diseases
   }
}
```

To add additional data, you just need to add more triples to the graph pattern:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/alexandrina/ontologies/2013/3/myOntology#>
INSERT DATA { 
GRAPH <http://www.semanticweb.org/alexandrina/ontologies/2013/3/myOntology>
   {
    :Cough a :Diseases ;
           rdfs:label "Cough"@en , "Tusea"@ro .
   }
}
```

Note that the graph pattern

```
:Cough a :Diseases ;
       rdfs:label "Cough"@en , "Tusea"@ro .
```

is equivalent to the more verbose pattern

```
:Cough a :Diseases .
:Cough rdfs:label "Cough"@en .
:Cough rdfs:label "Tusea"@ro .
```